# 400 Error While using Google Speech to text API

Tags: html, speech-to-text

I've Created a html form which Post the .flac file to google Speech to text API.
My code is as follow

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="audio/x-flac; rate=16000">
</head>
<body>
<form method=POST action="http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?lang=en-us&client=chromium">
<input type="file">
<input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
</body>
```

But whenever I post the audio google respond 
**400. That’s an error.
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. Content-Type should be of the form: audio/xxx; rate=yyy**

I need solution.

Answer (score 0):

"400. Thatâ€™s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. Missing parameter: key Thatâ€™s all we know."

This is what I get. I have even sent a request with a key and still 400, only without the "Missing Parameter:key" part